# dbus (glib) and second socket for TCP

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, tcp, dbus

I'm doing my first steps with dbus (using the glib C API) and have already my problems with the GLib. The Lib is serving the dbus data in the main loop

```
g_main_loop_run(loop);
```

For my application I do need a second socket acting as a TCP-IP server. How can I use both sockets if they are blocking? The application is running on an embedded hardware (linux) and has only very limited resources, so unfortunately multithreading is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, read [the manual](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html). It contains lots of information that directly answers your question. In particular, you can create a `GSource` by calling `g_source_new`. As part of this, a set of callbacks are associated with the new gsource. Then you use something like `g_source_add_unix_fd` to add the socket fd to the gsource. Finally use `g_source_attach` to attach your gsource to the main context (or whatever context you want). Then your callbacks will be invoked as part of the main loop whenever your socket has an event.